# Macro in a loop?

Tags: loops, macros, preprocessor

```
for(x;x<crap;x++)
{
    macro(x,y);
}
```

How is this handled by preprocessor? Is this loop unrolled or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro is expanded before the code is compiled - it doesn't matter whether it's in a loop or anywhere else.

```
#define macro(x, y) doSomething(x, y)
for(x;x<crap;x++){
    macro(x,y);
}
```

will expand to:

```
for(x;x<crap;x++){
    doSomething(x,y);
}
```

The context surrounding `macro(x,y)` has no effect on how the preprocessor expands it.

(The preprocessor doesn't even know what programming language you're using - it could be C, Python, Brainfuck or a letter to your bank manager and it would expand macros just the same way.)

Comment: The preprocessor _does_ have to know what language is being used.  Before macro replacement, the source has to be decomposed into preprocessing tokens, which are defined by the C and C++ language standards and are in some cases different between the two languages.  During evaluation of conditional directives, whether `true` and `false` are handled as boolean values is language-dependent (they are in C++ but they are not in C).  There are many other subtleties.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` macros can be thought of as a search and replace before compilation action happens. This means whatever your macro equates to will be directly substituded in its reference inside your code. No, the loop is no unrolled.